# iOS - Store into database

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem. I have a UITextView of writing text and store wit. The problem is that the text that I write is editable.

Answer (score 0):

Store the UITextView's `attributedText` archived into an NSData. SQLite will accept this as binary data. To retrieve, reverse the steps.

Note that the resulting text will not be searchable. If you want that, store the `text` *and* the `attributedText`.

Comment: I'm telling you to store the UITextView's `attributedText` archived into an NSData. SQLite will accept this as binary data.